# DM_EXEC_SESSIONS not returning active connections

Tags: sql-server, session, execute-as

I am using `SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS` to get all active SQL Server connections from my system. I know that if the logged user has no VIEW SERVER STATE permission, only the logged user is shown, otherwise all users.

But I do not want to give all basic users  the VIEW SERVER STATE permission (for security), but I need to get all users. So I made the following function WITH EXECUTE as option:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.allusers(@DUMMY CHAR(5))
RETURNS  @rtnTable TABLE
(
LOGINAIKA datetime,
TYOASEMA nchar(128),
LOGINNIMI varchar(50),
OHJELMA varchar(50), 
WKAYTTAJA nchar(128)
)
WITH EXECUTE AS 'poweruser'

as
BEGIN
--print USER_NAME()
INSERT @rtnTable

SELECT LOGIN_TIME AS LOGINAIKA,CAST(host_name AS nchar(128)) AS TYOASEMA,
LOGIN_NAME AS LOGINNIMI, PROGRAM_NAME AS OHJELMA,
NT_DOMAIN+'\'+CAST(nt_user_name AS nchar(128)) AS WKAYTTAJA FROM   SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS
WHERE PROGRAM_NAME LIKE 'J%'
and DB_NAME(database_id)=DB_NAME()
order by PROGRAM_NAME, LOGIN_NAME 
RETURN
END
```

The poweruser has VIEW SERVER STATE permission, but the function returns an empty result set, why?

Is there a way to get all connections for a basic user?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by setting the trustworthy property of the database in which the function is created. NB: I don't recommend that as a best practice as it opens up a pretty big security hole.

Alternatively, you can go through the exercise of creating a certificate-based login and use module signing.

Comment: I tried to set trustworthy=true, but no help. Module signing seems to be a complicated process.